# Google maps API for live traffic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, nodes

I am getting direction, distance, duration in my ionic google maps project.I want to get real time traffic updates,duration using ionic2 framework.Which api should i use?

Comment: Did you google this? For "Traffic" I would think you would use the "Traffic" Layer, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: traffic layer gives us the color in the map indicating whether there is traffic or not,but i want it to be dynamic like distance and duration should be according to traffic

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `setTrafficEnabled(enabled)` to true when you initialize the map. Consult the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/).